# Uninstalling python3 from Ubuntu stops the user interface from working

Tags: python, ubuntu, user-interface, nvidia

so, I had an error while booting Ubuntu and loading the user interface which resulted in the boot process stopping after checking file system integrity.

My error was just the same as in: https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w

So basically a message

```
dev/sda1: clean, 552599/6111232 files, 7119295/24414464 blocks
```

was the last thing to appear on the screen while booting.

This happened right after I uninstalled python3 from my system in order to re-install it, which I thought could help me solve a non-related bug involving a module that could not be imported.

Answer (score 0):

When python3 was purged, some dependencies of atp package `nvidia-driver-430`, which depend on python to run, stopped working. This stopped my GUI from being loaded after booting.

In the link for another question I shared above, the problem is solved purging nvidia's drivers and re-installing them. I've tried this for the python-related error and would like to add: that solution doesn't work if your problem was caused by a misuse of python3, like mine. The exact solution for that case would be:

- Ctrl+Alt+FX, X=1, 2, 3... in order to access the terminal after booting;
- Purging nvidia's drivers, `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`;
- Removing nvidia's python related dependencies, with `sudo apt autoremove`;
- Rebooting;
- Re-installing drivers: `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-XXX`;
- Solving other problems related with losing those drivers temporarily, after starting the GUI, such as not having GNOME installed (I think its purged somewhere in the process along with the drivers's dependencies) and having your dock mispositioned.